# Android App not show in Playstore for Backberry KeyOne

Tags: android, blackberry, google-play

One of my application is already LIVE on playstore and its quite working fine as well.

However, One of the user running [Blackberry-Keyone](http://www.gsmarena.com/blackberry_keyone-8508.php#india) which runs on Nougat and device is also having playstore installed. All other apps are showing in it but mine app is not shown if I'm searching in playstore for this specific device.

Question:
1. Do I need to do some extra work in order to make the app compatible for this blackberry-android devices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe is a matter of `minSdk`

Comment: @OussemaAroua As I said you, device is running on Nougat and I do have minsdkversion defined as 16(Kitkat).